# Error in production only when the user first hits the login screen

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In production only, when the user hits our login screen we get the following elmah eror

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Generated: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 16:50:35 GMT

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context)
   at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Unfortunately there is not alot going on there to give me any hints!

my *guess* is that it's some kind of racing condition under load where the routes arent' done loding yet when they are trying to be used... but it's only a guess.

Has anyone seen this error before?

We are loading the routes in the GlobalAsax Begine Request method.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
           if(RouteTable.Routes.Count == 0) {
                XmlConfigurator.Configure();
                ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("MainLog");
                log.Info("Logger started");

                //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
                //log.Info("RegisterAllAreas done");

                RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
                log.Info("RegisterRoutes done");

                try
                {
                    BootstrapStuctureMap.Bootstrap();
                    log.Info("Done Bootstrapping");

                    BootStrapAutoMapper.Configure();
                    log.Info("Done Automapping");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error("Error in Application_Start: ex = " + ex);
                    throw;
                }

                ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());
                log.Info("Done Building StructureMapControllerFactory");

                ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomModelBinder();
                ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new AnnotationsAndConventionsBasedModelMetaDataProvider();
            }
        }

 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");

            // you have to add this IgnoreRoute so that the PDFX pages get handled like a regular *.aspx page, not a MVC page. - EWB
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.pdfx");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new {favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?"});

            routes.MapRoute("StudentLookup_Return",
                            "StudentLookup/StudentLookup/{nextAction}/{nextController}",
                            new
                                {
                                    controller = "StudentLookup",
                                    action = "StudentLookup"
                                }
                );
            routes.MapRoute("StudentLookup_Id",
                            "StudentLookup/StudentLookup/{Id}",
                            new
                                {
                                    controller = "StudentLookup",
                                    action = "StudentLookup",
                                    Id = UrlParameter.Optional
                                }
                );
            routes.MapRoute("Default", // Route name
                            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                            new
                                {
                                    controller = "Home",
                                    action = "Index",
                                    id = UrlParameter.Optional
                                } // Parameter defaults
                );
        }
```

We belvie it showed up after some new Servers were rbought online, so it might have something to do with how those servers are configured.

I'm kind of throwing a Hail Mary here, that someone has seen this before and figured it out!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you registering routes during `Application_BeginRequest` instead of `Application_Start`? Same question for IoC, model binders, etc. Do you really want all of this to happen during each request?

Comment: If you look at the code it only lazy laods on the first request, but I get your point.(I didnt' write it :()

Comment: Couldn't `RouteTable.Routes` be `null` at this time ?